# Fast 64 bit comparison

Tags: c++, string, comparison

I'm working on a GUI framework, where I want all the elements to be identified by ascii strings of up to 8 characters (or 7 would be ok).

Every time an event is triggered (some are just clicks, but some are continuous), the framework would callback to the client code with the id and its value.

I could use actual strings and strcmp(), but I want this to be really fast (for mobile devices), so I was thinking to use char constants (e.g. int id = 'BTN1';) so you'd be doing a single int comparison to test for the id. However, 4 chars isn't readable enough.

I tried an experiment, something like-
long int id = L'abcdefg';

... but it looks as if char constants can only hold 4 characters, and the only thing making a long int char constant gives you is the ability for your 4 characters to be twice as wide, not have twice the amount of characters. Am I missing something here?

I want to make it easy for the person writing the client code. The gui is stored in xml, so the id's are loaded in from strings, but there would be constants written in the client code to compare these against.

So, the long and the short of it is, I'm looking for a cross-platform way to do quick 7-8 character comparison, any ideas?

Comment: How many million compares per second you do? Don't sweat it, it's fast enough with strings.

Comment: Do not use long-char's stick to ascii if your goal is to give your components a naming scheme.

Comment: This may not be portable.  According to the C++ standard, the value of a multicharacter literal (more than one character between 's) is implementation-defined.  Check your implementation's documentation to see that it is doing something you want, and check all implementations that can be used to see that they all do the same thing.

Comment: You're right, Pop and Hassan, I guess it's not going to kill the performance and doing 64bit strings is limiting from the outset. Gonna go with strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure this is not premature optimisation?  Have you profiled another GUI framework that is slow purely from string comparisons?  Why are you so sure string comparisons will be too slow?  Surely you're not doing *that* many string compares.  Also, consider strcmp should have a near optimal implementation, possibly written in assembly tailored for the CPU you're compiling for.

Anyway, other frameworks just use named integers, for example:

```
static const int MY_BUTTON_ID = 1;
```

You could consider that instead, avoiding the string issue completely.  Alternatively, you could simply write a helper function to convert a const char[9] in to a 64-bit integer.  This should accept a null-terminated string "like so" up to 8 characters (assuming you intend to throw away the null character).  Then your program is passing around 64-bit integers, but the programmer is dealing with strings.

Edit: here's a quick function that turns a string in to a number:

```
__int64 makeid(const char* str)
{
    __int64 ret = 0;
    strncpy((char*)&ret, str, sizeof(__int64));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of gui frameworks use int ids, but since my framework is based around an interface builder, either the coder has got to copy numbers into their code (inelegant) or the interface builder's gonna have to generate a header file with defines for each element, which won't work for some of the applications of the framework

I think you're totally right, I'm not doing that many compares, so I'll just stick with strings. I'm sure there's going to be bigger bottlenecks elsewhere in my code! Thanks!

Comment: Why pick this answer if your going to stick with strings, plus others have spent time answering your specific question ? ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't get the last part of my answer so I edited in a function to show.  If you call makeid("my id") you get back an __int64 with the string copied in to it.  That allows you to do integer comparisons with the convenience of the programmer entering strings.  Note it ignores any characters past the 8th.

Comment: Ah, thanks Ashley. I guess Ashley made it more clear to me that the strncmp penalty isn't likely to give me such a performance hit. The solution requires a good compromise between performance and conciseness/readability. I just did a basic speed test on OS X and strcmp seemed to be 8-9 times faster than an inlined makeid() whether it succeeds or fails. It's doing a few hundred million a second in each case anyway. (Ashley could you edit your post to be strncpy((char*)&ret, ...) cheers!)

Comment: I wouldn't have expected the speed difference to be 8-9x, but if you measured it, fair enough.  Fixed the syntax error, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to define your IDs as a union of a 64-bit integer and an 8-character string:

```
union ID {
  Int64 id;      // Assuming Int64 is an appropriate typedef somewhere
  char name[8];
};
```

Now you can do things like:

```
ID id;
strncpy(id.name, "Button1", 8);
if (anotherId.id == id.id) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easy to get pre-rolled Components**

[binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) for the win -- you get a [red-black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) tree from most STL implementations of set and map, so you might want to consider that.

[Intrusive versions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) of the STL containers perform MUCH better when you move the container nodes around a lot (in the general case) -- however they have quite a few caveats.

**Specific Opinion -- First Alternative**

If I was you I'd stick to a 64-bit integer type and bundle it in a intrusive container and use the library provided by boost. However if you are new to this sort of thing then use stl::map it is conceptually simpler to grasp, and it has less chances of leaking resources since there is more literature and guides out there for these types of containers and the best practises.

**Alternative 2**

The problem you are trying to solve I believe: is to have a global naming scheme which maps to handles. You can create a mapping of names to handles so that you can use the names to retrieve handles:

```
// WidgetHandle is a polymorphic base class (i.e., it has a virtual method),
// and foo::Luv implement WidgetHandle's interface (public inheritance)
foo::WidgetHandle * LuvComponent = 
          Factory.CreateComponent<foo::Luv>( "meLuvYouLongTime");
....

.... // in different function
foo::WidgetHandle * LuvComponent = 
          Factory.RetrieveComponent<foo::Luv>("meLuvYouLongTime");
```

Alternative 2 is a common idiom for IPC, you create an IPC type say a pipe in one process and you can ask the kernel for to retrieve the other end of the pipe by name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I was looking for the least LOC version, least hassle for the programmer, whilst trying to make it as fast as possible. I've got the component retrieval part of it sorted, it was just working out which component the event came from.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) can be useful for this problem, turning string compares into pointer compares.

Comment: I like the idea of comparing just the pointers but I'm trying to get a solution that's optimal also for the coder's point of view (maybe I just can't have the best of both worlds) e.g.

void controlClicked(sometype id, void *value) {
    if(id==SOME_MACRO('myButton')) {
        doSomethingWith(value);
    } else if(id==SOME_MACRO('mySlider')) {
        doSomethingElse(value);
    }
}
With the literals, 'myButton' and 'mySlider', in the code like that, there's less code for the programmer to write.

Maybe I could just turn SOME_MACRO() into a hashing function...

Answer (score 0):

I see a distinction between easily read identifiers in your code, and the representation being passed around.

Could you use an enumerated type (or a large header file of constants) to represent the identifier? The names of the enumerated types could then be as long and meaningful as you wish, and still fit in (I am guessing) a couple of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x, you'll be able to use [user-defined string literals](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#UD-literals), so you could add something like `7chars..id` or `"7chars.."id`:

```
template <char...> constexpr unsigned long long operator ""id();
constexpr unsigned long long operator ""id(const char *, size_t);
```

Although I'm not sure you can use `constexpr` for the second one.